# Making background image responsive in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I have made only in css something like this is it possible to that in bootstrap 3?

Here is what i need?

[image]

Edited

This is not fixed header, and in right corner there is also title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, On your background div, use background-size: cover.

```
.background-div {
  width: 100%;
  background: url("..") center center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possibly with the navbar-fixed-top class. You just add this to your navbar, then the navbar has a position absolute. Add a new class, we don't want to overwrite bootstrap's default classes. Give the class a top px. Place your image above the navbar. Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8mx75/). Or you could add a div and give the div a background-image and make that scalable.

```
.navbar-fixed-top-edit{
     top:150px;
}
```

Comment: I dont want this to be fixed on top

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more then?

Comment: You see this is when is fixed at top i dont want to do that

Comment: Redefine your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an image responsive all you need is to use this bootstrap class `class="img-responsive"`. If you want to make a div responsive witch has a background image, you have to set your `width to 100%`. If you don't like how the background is resizing, you always have an option to have 4 diferent background's for each enviroment type (xs, sm, md, lg).